# Choosing $k$ so that given numbers are between $2k\pi$ and $2k\pi+3\pi$

Tags: inequality

So I am studying a proof, and at one point, it states that for all $x$ and $y$ for whom it holds true to $|x-y| < \pi$ and $y \ge x$, we can pick an integer $k$ so $$2k\pi \le x < 2k\pi + 2\pi$$ and then it follows that $$2k\pi \le x \le y < 2k\pi + 3\pi$$

Are both these statements true in isolation, or combined? Can we always do this? If so, then can we also say that we instead pick $k$ so $$2k\pi \le x < 2k\pi + \pi$$ from where we conclude that $$2k\pi \le x \le y \le 2k\pi + 2\pi\ ?$$

I'm trying to rewrite a proof and show something different, but above is confusing me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can. Just take $k = \lfloor x/2\pi \rfloor$.

As for the second statement: no, we can't. If $x = 7\pi/2$, you won't be able to find a suitable $k$, because if $k = 1$ then $x > 3\pi = 2k\pi + \pi$ and if $k = 2$ then $x < 4 \pi = 2k\pi$.